# Synchronize Outlook RSS feeds and a Windows phone

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, rss, windows-phone

I use Outlook desktop for reading my feeds. I would like to sync these feeds in order to check them on my windows phone, Nokia lumia 620.

Answer (score 0):

When in Outlook on your Lumia 620 follow these steps:

1. Expand the application bar (bottom menu) by tapping the ellipsis ...
2. Tap 'folders'
3. Tap 'show all folders'
4. under 'RSS Feeds' select the feed you want to sync.

Comment: Michal : I don't have "rss feeds" folder on the phone outlook app.